# Creating branch to uncommitted works

Tags: git

I did a clone to remote repo and start working on the code. I did lot of things on the code adding, modifying and deleting but haven't add/commit/push yet. Now I don't want to push these changes to remote repo because I have to complete all related task. At the same time I need to try different approach too.
So how can I save current changes in "new branch" without losing my work, then create new branch and start working on any one of those branch.

At the end I am think of having something like this:

master ---> donesofar --> trynew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new branch, and commit the code on it, and then create another new branch to work upon.

```
git checkout -b donesofar
git add . && git commit -m "msg"
git checkout -b trynew
```

So now, you will be on a branch `trynew`, which will have all your changes. The changes in `donesofar` are going to be preserved since you are not working on them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could also 'stash' your changes for later. From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash:

`Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory and the index, but want to go back to a clean working directory. The command saves your local modifications away and reverts the working directory to match the HEAD commit.`

Just stay on your local branch and type `git stash save` and it will stash away your current changes and revert back to your most recent HEAD commit. You can restore your stash later by typing `git stash apply`. This will re-add all the changes you'd saved back onto whatever branch you are currently working on, in an uncommitted state.